# Getting the ID of the current logged in user in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

how can i get the id of the current logged in user?
 I search and got this code :

```
Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString()
```

but it only gets the name of the current user, what I want to get is the ID of the current user, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having right code, but you don't need `toString()` method.

```
var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
string username = currentUser.UserName //** get UserName
Guid userID = currentUser.ProviderUserKey //** get user ID
```

Answer (score 2):

try `Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;`

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()
```