# Insert UserID of Logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, user-controls, insert

Ok i have a insert statement that inserts into a table Rented it stores the `dvdID` retrieved via a `DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text`,

I also want to collect the `UserId` and store it into the `Rented` table.

How would i go about obtaining the logged in User ID

**My Code**

```
da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Rented (DVDID, UserID) VALUES (@rent, @user)", conn);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rent", DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", ???);
```

Comment: When you say "Logged in User ID" is it the User logged into your Application, or is it the Network / LAN User ID? Depending on which one, either of the 2 answers below should work.

Comment: Logied in to my application(using asp.net membership)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
var currentUser = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
string username = currentUser.UserName //** get UserName
Guid userID = currentUser.ProviderUserKey //** get user ID
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18656566/690329) thread.

And add like this:

```
 da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", userID );
```

Comment: Thank you, how would i user it in my query

Comment: Check the last line of my answer.

Comment: Brilliant, but when I apply this I get a Error 20 The name 'Membership' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Beep, hope you are working on VS; then right click on `Membership` and select `Resolve`. it's under `System.Web.Security` namespace.

Comment: Ok so what i got is   
             `da.InsertCommand = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Rented (DVDID, UserID) VALUES (@rent, @username)", conn);
            var currentUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
            string username = currentUser.UserName; //** get UserName


            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rent", DG_Latest.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
            da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", currentUser);` But when i run it i get data mismatch error

Comment: You mentioned userid in question. It should be guid type.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

  (OR)

string userName = Environment.UserName
```

Well in case you want to get the userid then then below code line should work fine

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```

Comment: depends on you, do you ant to insert that id somewhere in your DB. Cause if it's coming from your DB then why do you need to reinsert it?

Comment: well the idea is to track user rentals, i will out put this to admin, and build a new query later to display to individual members there rentals

Comment: @Beep, that's what I said; if you needed to insert this userid to some other table as FK then go ahead and insert and in such case, yes you need the insert command.